# How to create a synonym where the dot dentifies row elements

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to define this constants: Bool.True, Bool.False, and Bool.Null, to make more readable SQL queries.

One possibility is to create a table storing the values for true and false, and creating a synonym named "Bool", for the table, but then I cannot use "Bool.True", because that would  be a column named "True", instead of a specific value in a row.

Is there any way to do it, or something equivalent? (One possibility would be to create a package named "Bool", with functions named "True_", "False_", and "Null_")

Comment: You certainly can't create a synonym for a value, no.  But where will you use this?  If in PL/SQL you can just define constants and use those.

Comment: @Tony Andrews I want to use it outside of PL/SQL. I want to populate table rows with Bool.True, and check if a column row is equal to Bool.Something

Comment: You can't  do that.

Comment: You can create the package you suggested, which will work - except you won't be able to use the Null_ function, because the only way to check for nulls is using `is null` or `is not null`.

Comment: With your table idea you could write queries like `where is_happy = (select true_ from bool)` - but I doubt you want to do that!

Comment: Use 'Y', 'N', and NULL. Your life will be much, much simpler.

Comment: Or T/F/null, or 0/1/null, or whatever makes most sense to you and other developers. But add a check constraint so only the specific values you decide on can be put into the column. I'm struggling to see how anything else would make "more readable SQL queries".

Comment: @Bob Jarvis That's a bad idea because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants

Comment: @Alex Poole one of many problems is that a year in the future/another person will read the code, and do not know if F means False, or will write 1 instead of T

Comment: The article you linked too says "The constants 1 and 0 are sometimes used to represent the boolean values True and False in programming languages without a boolean type such as older versions of C.". I agree it's a problem, but a constraint limits it - but doesn't stop someone getting opposite meanings. Having a package constant for each flag value helps, but you can't force someone to refer to those either. (If someone can confuse T/F, say because they don't speak English, will they know what True/False mean either?) Overcomplicating it causes its own problems.

Comment: @Alex Poole. The package helps to clarify the meaning of "true_", but cannot enforce his use. A table can enforce his use with a foreign key, but cannot have a clear name. That's why I'm looking on synonyms, or something...

Comment: @Tony Andrews Thank. That's a good idea.(boolean looks simple, but there are more complex possible types. I only use boolean as a simple example).

Comment: ¿Maybe is possible to create a table named "True", with a single value, and other named "False", with a single value, and make a foreign key which references some class of join of "True" and "False"?

Comment: @cisak: I wasn't aware that 'Y' or 'N' were numbers. :-) 'Y' for 'YES', 'N' for 'NO', 'T' for true, 'F' for false - and NULL is NULL is a relational database. You can mess around all you like trying to come up with some sort of One True Boolean Representation Of Which All Others Are But Shadows - but in the end you are going to breed yourself a zoo full of problems. But heck, I've only been doing this software thing for 40+ years - I've still got a lot to learn. :-) Best of luck.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis Yes, everything is a number inside computers. Data and code is stored as a sequence of 1/0. A great thing to learn are good coding practices. Some books that comes to my mind is Herb Sutter's C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices and Steve McConnell's Code Complete.

Comment: Oracle does not *yet* support the boolean data type, which would solve your problem with it. https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2633 has been raised for it. Until then, we lesser mortals get the job done with other data types (e.g. varchar2(1)), along with constraints, and using conventions such as Y/N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The package helps to clarify the meaning of "true_", but cannot enforce his use.

You could use object types and subtypes to do both, but it's not terribly pretty, particularly if this is only a simple example; but just to demonstrate:

```
create type bool as object (
  flag number(1)
)
not final not instantiable
/

create type bool_false under bool (
  constructor function bool_false return self as result
)
final
/
show errors;

create type body bool_false as
  constructor function bool_false return self as result is
  begin
    self.flag := 0;
    return;
  end;
end;
/

create type bool_true under bool (
  constructor function bool_true return self as result
) final
/

create type body bool_true as
  constructor function bool_true return self as result is
  begin
    self.flag := 1;
    return;
  end;
end;
/
```

Then you can have a table with a column using the supertype (which isn't instantiable), and you can put instances of either type into it:

```
create table t42 (id number, bool_flag bool);
insert into t42 values (1, bool_true());
insert into t42 values (2, bool_false());
insert into t42 values (3, null);

select * from t42;

        ID BOOL_FLAG(FLAG)
---------- ---------------
         1 BOOL_TRUE(1)
         2 BOOL_FALSE(0)
         3

3 rows selected.
```

or filter on it:

```
select * from t42 where bool_flag = bool_true();

        ID BOOL_FLAG(FLAG)
---------- ---------------
         1 BOOL_TRUE(1)

1 row selected.
```

You can't create an index on the object-type column though, which might be an issue. You could have an FBI but then queries get even more complicated.

---

It would still be simpler to just use a scalar data type and check constraint, e.g. with a number:

```
create table t42 (id number, bool_flag number(1) check (bool_flag in (1,0)));
insert into t42 values (1, 1);
insert into t42 values (2, 0);
insert into t42 values (3, null);
```

Or a single character, T?F or Y/N or whatever works for you:

```
create table t42 (id number, bool_flag varchar2(1) check (bool_flag in ('T','F')));
insert into t42 values (1, 'T');
insert into t42 values (2, 'F');
insert into t42 values (3, null);
```

Or if you're really concerned that future developers will be confused about the meaning of T and F, you could even store whole words - at extra cost in terms of storage, of course:

```
create table t42 (id number, bool_flag varchar2(5) check (bool_flag in ('TRUE','FALSE')));
insert into t42 values (1, 'TRUE');
insert into t42 values (2, 'FALSE');
insert into t42 values (3, null);
```

And if they're confused by true/false, they'll be equally confused by something like `bool_true` and `bool_false`...

Comment: Hardly.... and I still think this is overkill. There's still nothing stopping someone putting the *wrong* (object) value in the column, any more than there would be with a scalar data type and check constraint.